# PyGreSQL on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Is PyGreSQL unsupported on Heroku, or am I doing something wrong in my requirements.txt file?

```
web.py==0.36
PyGreSQL
```

When I run pip locally, everything installs fine. When I try to deploy, I get the following error message.

```
-----> Installing dependencies using pip version 1.0.2
   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): web.py==0.36 in ./.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
   Downloading/unpacking PyGreSQL (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FP%2FPyGreSQL%2FPyGreSQL-4.0.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package PyGreSQL
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
         File "/tmp/build_35fg1nd48mese/.heroku/venv/build/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 98, in <module>
           mk_include()
         File "/tmp/build_35fg1nd48mese/.heroku/venv/build/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 69, in mk_include
           for f in os.listdir(pg_include_dir_server):
       OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server'
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

     File "/tmp/build_35fg1nd48mese/.heroku/venv/build/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 98, in <module>

       mk_include()

     File "/tmp/build_35fg1nd48mese/.heroku/venv/build/PyGreSQL/setup.py", line 69, in mk_include

       for f in os.listdir(pg_include_dir_server):

   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/include/postgresql/8.4/server'

   ----------------------------------------
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
   Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PyGreSQL library does not support PostgreSQL 9.1 at the moment, and therefore is incompatible with Heroku.

Comment: This info is very outdated. Please, update your answer